# Why did Moses reappear before Pharaoh after saying he would not?

Tags: exegesis, exodus

Why did Pharoah claim in Exodus 10:28 that he would kill Moses if Moses ever stood before him again; and then in vs. 29, Moses confirms that "You have spoken correctly, I shall never see your face again!" NASB

Then, in the next chapter (11), Moses leaves Pharoah's presence after threatening him with the final plague of the death of the firstborn (Exodus 11:10).

Was it an emotional outburst on the part of both parties? I don't have the context of understanding Hebrew language enough to be sure of a definitive answer.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  Please take our Tour to see how we are different to other sites: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour